# Detect Google "stylized" photo?

Tags: post-processing, artifacts, android

Google on Pixel phone **stylizes** some photos. Selection of photos to stylize is arbitrary (happens to some photos when you upload, no user selection to trigger) and what exactly happens in stylizing is  [not known](https://support.google.com/photos/thread/124227/please-explain-what-a-stylised-photo-is-and-how-i-can-learn-what-s-been-changed?hl=en) (though some things like brightness, color and size reduction to probably save on space are obvious to see).

Is it possible for anyone else to detect that a photo has been stylized (of course, without comparing with original)? Maybe some artifact as a result of stylization? I suspect that the answer is no, but wanted to be sure (I can detect by the 3 stars icon in the photos app)

This is original photo

[image]

This is the stylized version

[image]

Note that both have been scaled down to png format to meet upload size restrictions.

Edit : [Here are the originals](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=kZB6GIXZ82PkuJIbPdSYRw4RIjLolQmnpYp7). Google adds "EFFECTS" in the stylized photo name

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://support.google.com/photos/thread/108576230/where-are-stylized-photos?hl=en) if that is what you are asking about? That said, it looks like a terrible, undocumented and uncontrolled feature, thank you Google...

Comment: @MrUpsidown thanks, I had seen it earlier while trying to search what happens in stylizing and linked the three year old answer, that says "nobody knows" :( // agree with your observations :)

Comment: In this instance, the original already looks like a painting, it's been so smoothed. I doubt there's any way to know [without the snappy little icon] whether Google added the extra 'punch' or if it was done by the originator. You could do this in Photoshop, Gimp or any of the modern 'push-button-fixit' apps.

Comment: So do you not see the 3 stars icon on those photos?

Comment: Well, I cheated (have looked at the original), but if anything, the stylized photo looks like it has been processed with software-based [High-Dynamic Range (HDR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-dynamic-range_imaging).

Comment: @AndrewT. to do HDR, you need several different exposures in the first place so I wouldn't call that *HDR* unless the original was indeed shot in HDR mode. To me, it looks more like a slight curves adjustment, pushed whites and contrast (maybe clarity) increase. Not easy to tell exactly what was applied given the size of the images (and the screen I am looking at right now). Looks like it introduced quite a lot of noise (this is particularily visible in the sky). Hard to tell without seeing the original unless you know very well what your camera should output.

Comment: It does look like it's been very aggressively smoothed even in the original. All the Stylize process seems to have done is to further overpush the vibrance/saturation & increase the contrast. There's no way to know where that was done. Here's a one button fix in Luminar showing a reasonably similar push [left orig, right tweaked]  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrK5j.jpg

Comment: Blue tint, in the sky, looks slightly different, more on the turquoise side. Bottom half of the picture seems to be more saturated, the white balance pushed on the yellow side, contrast was added too and the whites are pushed as well. It *looks* to me that the effects applied aren't uniform on the entire photo but I might be wrong.

Comment: TBH, if I would see a *stylized* version of one of my own photos, I'd probably know instantly that it is not the original because I know very well how my images look in the first place + I know I would never edit them that way. *Is it possible to detect that a photo has been stylized without comparing with original?* I believe only you can answer this question. If you are familiar enough with how your original pictures look, you should be able to tell, but that's only my opinion...

Comment: @MrUpsidown, so it looks to be complex tweak? Not as simple as applying an effect, which is uniformly applied

Comment: That's honestly hard (impossible?) to confirm. Google algorithms... How does it work? I guess only Google devs could answer that question. I suppose an algorithm could be able to determine that the top half is the sky and to apply a certain effect to that part of the pic only, the bottom half is a bit too dark so another effect gets applied to that part, and so on. But that's only a supposition.

Comment: These are not the original photos; but scaled down versions, which removes most artefacts. One could possibly look at the histogram of the full-size pictures, the original picture being smooth, and the stylized photos showing peaks and gaps.

Comment: @xenoid as mentioned in Q, I am aware that the size is reduced but didn't realize that artifacts would be removed. Thanks for inputs

Comment: @xenoid I don't know a thing about histogram interpretation but am wondering if the peaks and gaps are unusual in a normal photo and therefore can tell if it's stylized?

Comment: In a normal photo, colors are rather random so the histogram is smooth. Editing colors tend to quantize them. Some colors value are no longer used, and some other are overused, so the histogram is quite different ("haircomb"). But scaling down blur things and smoothens the histogram again.

Comment: @xenoid thanks for the inputs :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to find all of the images that Google has stylised for you is to navigate to https://photos.google.com/search/_m10_Saved%20creations

It's at the bottom of Explore

[image]

You'll see 'Color pop', 'Pano', 'Stylised photo' when clicking through.

You can also use the search term "Stylised Photo" from the main search bar on photos.google.com, or this URL https://photos.google.com/search/Stylised%20photo

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware of the link at the end of answer though and that's far more easier and may help others as well

Comment: The trouble with the initial premise upon which the question is based is that you're trying to identify **where** the edit has been done. This is impossible to discern [without Google's helpful overlays] because it could literally have been done anywhere.

Comment: @Tetsujin I  get it. You may like to expand it into an answer, since I did suspect that one can't identify and was looking for expert opinion. If you decide to answer please do elaborate on the changes observed based on originals. (since "where" edit has been done translates to "what" has been edited!) Thanks

Comment: I'm sure really sure I can spin it up into an answer. Basically, all I can say is "you can't tell". Even knowing *what* was done gives you zero clue as to *where* it was done.